# Safari fails CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, safari

I am using a [DynamicPolicyProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx) to determine if a request from a domain is allowed or not in an Asp.Net Web API 2.2 application.  In order make that determination I am using a couple of RegEx patterns defined in the Web.Config

```
 <applicationSettings>
<MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="AllowedDomains" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value>
      <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <string>http://localhost</string>
        <string>http*://*.domain1.com</string>
        <string>http*://*.domain2.com</string>
      </ArrayOfString>
    </value>
  </setting>
</MyApp.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

Then within my `DynamicPolicyProviderFactory` I create a RegEx I can use:

```
 //constructor
 public DynamicPolicyProviderFactory(IEnumerable allowedOrigins)//allowedDrigins is the strings passed from the config        {
        _allowed = new HashSet<Regex>();

        foreach (string pattern in allowedOrigins.Cast<string>()
            .Select(Regex.Escape)
            .Select(pattern => pattern.Replace("*", "w*")))
        {
            _allowed.Add(new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        }

        if (_allowed.Count > 0)
            return;

        //if nothing is specified, we assume everything is.
        _allowed.Add(new Regex(@"https://\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        _allowed.Add(new Regex(@"http://\w*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
    }

 public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var route = request.GetRouteData();
        var controller = (string)route.Values["controller"];
        var corsRequestContext = request.GetCorsRequestContext();
        var originRequested = corsRequestContext.Origin;
        var policy = GetPolicyForControllerAndOrigin(controller, originRequested);
        return new CustomPolicyProvider(policy);
    }

    //this is where the magic happens
    private CorsPolicy GetPolicyForControllerAndOrigin(string controller, string originRequested)
    {
        // Do lookup to determine if the controller is allowed for
        // the origin and create CorsPolicy if it is (otherwise return null)

        if (_allowed.All(a => !a.Match(originRequested).Success))
            return null;

        var policy = new CorsPolicy();

        policy.Headers.Add("accept");
        policy.Headers.Add("content-type");

        policy.Origins.Add(originRequested);
        policy.Methods.Add("GET");
        policy.Methods.Add("POST");
        policy.Methods.Add("PUT");
        policy.Methods.Add("DELETE");
        policy.Methods.Add("OPTIONS");

        return policy;
    }
```

Assuming the request origin is: http://sub.domain1.com and the script location is http://sub.domain1.com:8080.  This works perfectly in Chrome, IE, FireFox, and Opera, but it fails in Safari.  What is strange is that the error Safari gives in the browser console is

```
Failed to load resource: Origin http://sub.domain1.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

What could be happening?

Another oddity I observed is that if both my origin and script location are http:sub.domain1.com:8080 CORS request are made by Safari (and pass) but other browsers correctly treat this as same origin.

**edit:**  I have found that if I put a breakpoint where `GetPolicyForControllerAndOrigin` returns null, it is never hit and a policy is created and returned properly.

**edit 2:**  I inspected the response from the server to the OPTIONS request by Safari and have found that the headers `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers are missing from the response. Also, on the request side, Safari is not adding the `Host` header.  Is that required?  Is that why it is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was with the OPTIONS request by Safari.  I was only allowing `accept` and `content-type` for allowed headers, but Safari was asking for `origin` as well.